# Do we ever reason about a non-associative algebra without embedding it in an associative algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, philosophy, associativity, nonassociative-algebras

This question most certainly contains some errors in phrasing.  It is on the subject of the philosophy of mathematics, and it is hard to stay precise when reaching towards the fundamentals of math.

The associative property is astonishingly fundamental.  More than once I've heard musings that it isn't clear if the associative property is fundamental to the universe, or merely fundamental to how the brain works.  While non associative algebgras certainly exist, it is the associative ones that seem to form the backbone of mathematics.

When studying non associative algebras, it is common to first embed the algebra in an associative one first and then do the reasoning there.  It is my belief (please correct me if I'm wrong) that the syntactic reasoning of proof theory is constructed using associative data structures  and operations (strings with associative operations like concatenation).

Do we ever study a non associative algebra without somehow framing it inside an associative approach?  I ask because I have not been able to imagine what that might look like.  If we do, what do we gain by such an approach?

Comment: "*Do we ever study a non associative algebra without somehow framing it inside an associative approach? *" Yes, there is an area called non-associative algebras, about not necessarily associative algebras. Definitely we have a theory which is not based on "framing it inside an associative approach". There are many books on it, e.g., the one by Schafer.

Comment: Lie theory? Although representations in associative algebras (e.g. matrix algebras) and the universal enveloping algebra are certainly tools that are central to the subject, there's plenty that can be said without them.

Comment: I think this question over-states its premise, etc., but is reasonable. E.g., to understand Lie algebras, we really _do_ look at the (associative!) universal enveloping algebra, for many reasons. I have scant idea about other non-associative algebras than Lie algebras...

Comment: There are several similar instances in mathematics. For example we have Euclidean geometry and then also *non-Euclidean* geometry. Although a Euclidean space is "fundamental to the universe", it is still possible and interesting to study hyperbolic or spherical geometry. Certainly we "gain a lot by such an approach", and generalisations often lead to a new theory, with new methods. It is not true that we always frame it inside a special case.

Comment: The octonions are an example of a non-associative algebra that AFAIK is never studied in the way you suggest. What we do is use the definition of the algebra and the *alternative law*. What we gain is lots of information about an algebra that is interesting and important.